# How to use Ext.ComponentQuery.query with nested attributes

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch

How to use Ext.ComponentQuery.query with nested attributes in Sencha Touch?

e.g

```
var myHardtoGetObj = topLevelView.down('someview[config.categoryCfg.id=1]')[0];
```

This gets me "uncaught error"

given :

```
Ext.define('SomeView', {
    xtype : 'someview',
    config : {
        categoryCfg : {
            id   : 5,
            name : 'someName' 
        }
    }
});
```

Is this possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The canonical way of doing things like that is adding a custom pseudo class matcher:

```
Ext.ComponentQuery.pseudos.hasCategoryId = function(components, selector) {
    var result = [],
        c, i, len;

    for (i = 0, len = components.length; i < len; i++) {
        c = components[i];

        if (c.config.categoryCfg && c.config.categoryCfg.id == selector) {
            result.push(c);
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Then you can use this pseudo class both globally with `Ext.ComponentQuery.query`, and locally with methods like `query`, `down`, etc.:

```
var allMatched, someComponent;

allMatched = Ext.ComponentQuery.query(':hasCategoryId(1)');
someComponent = myPanel.down(':hasCategoryId(42)');
```

See more ways to skin the cat in [ComponentQuery doc](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/apidocs/#!/api/Ext.ComponentQuery).

Comment: Thanks a lot I really liked this approach.

Comment: Where would it be the best place to declare this pseudo? launch method of the controller where I will use the pseudo?

Comment: Ext.ComponentQuery is global, and its pseudos are also global. I would suggest placing this code somewhere at the top, so it would be available throughout the application.

Answer (score 2):

This really is an interesting question. There doesn't seem to be an absolutely straightforward solution, however there is a rather quick workaround. You can modify your view code to:

```
Ext.define('SomeView', {
   xtype : 'someview',
   config : {
       categoryCfg : {
           id   : 5,
           name : 'someName' 
       }
   },

   hasCategoryId: function (id) {
       return this.getCategoryCfg().id == id;
   }
});
```

Then you can make a query like this:

```
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('someview{hasCategoryId(1)}');
```

or

```
topLevelView.down('someview{hasCategoryId(1)}');
```

***Note***: The syntax of the selector is **xtype{memberMethod()}** without a space in between. This way both selectors must match (the same way as **.class1.class2** in CSS). Also the selectors must be in this order, because the result set is filtered by each selector in order and if some of the components don't have the hasCategoryId method it will break with just '{hasCategoryId(1)}'

Comment: this indeed is an option,but as a friend told me - wonder how performant is this against using actually an attribute ...

Answer (score 1):

Although not exactly answering the question but you can do a little work around to get it to work.

you can add update method to your nestedConfig like so

```
Ext.define('myCoolClass', {
    config : {
        nestedConfig : {
            nestedId : 5
        },

        nestedId : null
    },

    updateNestedConfig: function (nestedConfig) {
        if (nestedConfig.nestedId) {
            this.setNestedId(nestedConfig.nestedId);
        }
    }
});
```

By doing that you now have access to normal component query attribute

```
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('[nestedId=555]')
```

As an example. If you take a look at Sencha source code they use this quite a lot like in NavigationView and TabPanels

Comment: having twice nestedId doesn't sound right in that case I rather just get rid of nestedConfig at all and define all attributes at the config level ... plus would have to create another function just to set the value ...

Comment: btw convention says it should be 'MyCoolClass' ;)